# What's the differences between broken pipe vs bad file descriptor from closed socket error in python

Tags: python, sockets

Both this exceptions are thrown when socket's already closed. But I haven't understood what the differences between them yet. someone can help me? thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You would get bad file descriptor if you close a socket and then try to read from/write to it. Broken pipe is when you try to write to a socket that has been closed on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

> Both this exceptions are thrown when socket's already closed

No. Broken pipe, connection reset, etc., occur when the *peer* has closed the *connection.* Bad file descriptors, socket closed, etc., occur when *you* have already closed the *socket.*